# Why COUNT(*) of multiple rows of SELECT 1 is always 1?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (

SELECT 1 FROM ... 
UNION SELECT 1 FROM ...
UNION SELECT 1 FROM ...

) as tmp_table
```

Despite the result set including multiple rows, `COUNT(*)` will always return 1... why?

Comment: I suspect you haven't tried running `SELECT 1 FROM ... UNION SELECT 1 FROM ... UNION SELECT 1 FROM ...`

Comment: @ta.speot.is: yes, I have. The answer Chris gave works now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UNION SELECT` automatically groups your results, meaning that you will not see duplicate rows. What you need is `UNION ALL SELECT...`, then your results will not be grouped and you will see duplicate rows.

Duplicate rows meaning, because you always select 1, so it groups by 1.

Comment: Technically it's doing a distinct not a grouping but the outcome is the same